# What do the appleprofilepolicyd and wdhelper processes do?

Tags: activity-monitor, macos, profile-manager

I found in activity monitor appleprofilepolicyd and wdhelper but after googling a while didn't found any interesting information:

- `wdhelper` - could be a webdrive or webdav - found only wdhelper.dll but nothing really related to the process
- `appleprofilepolicyd` - something related to “Apple Profile Policy” ("captain obvious to the rescue!") - but still no related search results for it

What are theese processes do and what are they required for (dependencies)?

Answer (score 3):

From the Apple Developer man pages:

> appleprofilepolicyd is a system daemon that implements a policy for the services provided by AppleProfileFamily.  When an AppleProfileFamily user asks to perform an action, this daemon is invoked to make the final policy decision.

Essentially, this governs what apps, accounts, processes, etc. have access to what services and activities.

I believe wdhelper is a LaunchDaemon that is implemented by, for example, a WD MyBook drive when it is installed to the Mac.

Comment: sounds logically as well as the WebDrive and WebDAV

Comment: `wdhelper` in not related in any way with WD (Western Digital) disks. Look @'Charles Lindauer' answer which is rather short but right.

Answer (score 0):

wdhelper XPC helper tool for performing privileged operations for WirelessDiagnosticsSupport.framework

Comment: Could you clarify your answer?

Comment: See my qn http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158863/what-is-the-xpcd-executable-darwin-xpc3-service / @danielAzuelos

Answer (score 0):

`wdhelper` is a daemon launched from:
    /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.wdhelper.plist
which is located there:
    /usr/libexec/wdhelper
which is regularly running on your system as soon as you are using
a wireless (AirPort, Wi-Fi or WLAN) interface.

From my personnal analysis,
this daemon is in charge to guess which is the
nature of the wireless environnment:

- channels
- signal quality
- access control (802.1X, captive portal…)
- well known hot spots
- well known constructors misbehaviours

it does launch `nc` (netcat), `netstat`, `kextstat`, `ifconfig`, `ipconfig`, `scutil`, `airport` and `airportd`

it does also inspect the MacOS X system behaviour, most presumably because this daemon could become too intrusive, through the use of
`spindump`, `system_profiler`, `top`, `ioreg` and `killall` (in case processes fail that bad).